# How to execute thor actions in irb or rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to debug my gem's generators in `irb` or `rails c` and execute some commands, i.e.:

```
gsub_file
append_to_file
inject_into_file
```

What I should require in `irb` or `rails c` to make it work.
I've tried:

```
require 'thor'
require 'rails/generators'
require 'rails/generators/base'
```

but it didn't work.